# Beginner Trying to Find Out Why 2 Very Similar Sets of Code Have Very Different Results

Tags: ruby

The first set of code works

https://repl.it/Br7w/1069

```
def scramble_string(string, positions)
  scrambled=""
  idx=0
  while idx<string.length
    scrambled+=string[positions[idx]]
    idx+=1
  end
  puts scrambled
  return scrambled
end
```

It results in the following inputs/outputs:

> scramble_string("abcd", [3, 1, 2, 0]) == "dbca"
>
> scramble_string("markov", [5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0]) == "vkaorm"

On the other hand, this 2nd set doesn't work

https://repl.it/Br7w/1072

```
def scramble_string(string, positions)
  scrambled=string
  idx=0
  while idx<string.length
    scrambled[idx]=string[positions[idx]]
    idx+=1
  end
  puts scrambled
  return scrambled
end
```

It results in the following inputs/outputs:

> scramble_string("abcd", [3, 1, 2, 0]) == "dbcd"
>
> scramble_string("markov", [5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0]) == "vkkokv"

Please help me understand why the 2nd set doesn't work.

Comment: Are "dbca" and "vkaorm" the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby, strings are assigned by reference. That is, after

```
scrambled=string
```

any changes to `scrambled` will also change `string`.

If you replace that line with

```
scrambled=string.dup
```

which gives `scrambled` its own copy, then the functions will give the same output.

Comment: More specifically "object reference", which is a form of invisible pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the second `scrambled_string` method you're initializing your `scrambled` variable as the string is being passed as the first parameter, not as an empty string.

```
def scramble_string(string, positions)
  scrambled = ''
  idx = 0
  while idx < string.length
    scrambled[idx] = string[positions[idx]]
    idx += 1
  end
  scrambled
end

p scramble_string('abcd', [3, 1, 2, 0])
# => "dbca"
p scramble_string('markov', [5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0])
# => "vkaorm"
```

This is what happens in both cases:

```
markov           markov
v                v
markov           varkov
k                k
markov           vkrkov
a                k
markov           vkkkov
o                o
markov           vkkoov
r                k
markov           vkkokv
m                v
"vkaorm"         "vkkokv"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am still confused.

I understand that scrambled is not empty, but I don't understand why it doesn't work to simply replace each value of the scrambled string (that originates as having the values of the string string) rather than enter into an empty string.

Comment: Because assigning `scrambled` as `string` is like if you were taking the letters and replacing them, but if you initialize scramble as an empty string you're working during the whole `while` loop with the same value. See the edited answer.

Comment: @Emilio: It doesn't "originate as having the values of the `string` string", it *is* the `string` string. There is only *one* string in your second snippet. You assigned `scrambled` to be the same object as `string`.